# how to run multiple queries in one call in prisma orm with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, express, prisma

I am using Prisma **4.13** version with PostgreSQL & express for backend.

The back-end code needs to run 3-5 queries in API to get data. I want to run all these queries in one call. This is to save time that goes in call to db, execute queries and return data.
Is there a way to run multiple queries in one prisma call?